# Split a string and return the value based on the delimiter position

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a function in SQL Server to split the input string and return a part of the string based on the delimiter's position..

For instance. I have a string

```
str = kool_2214_live_dbp123
```

And if I parse the text, delimiter and the position of the delimiter. I would like to get the value after that delimiter

So, let's say we have a function which accepts 3 parameters

```
Splitfunction(str, delimiter, occurrence)
```

If I pass

```
Splitfunction(str , _ , 2)
```

the function should return the string `live`

```
Splitfunction(str , _ , 3)
```

should return the string `dbp123`

Thanks a ton in advance..

Answer (score 1):

First you need to split your string. There are a number of ways to do that. One way that I prefer, although other people like Aaron Betrand do not like, is this one from Jeff Moden. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

That one is particularly useful in situations like this one.

```
declare @str varchar(50) = 'kool_2214_live_dbp123'

select *
from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@str, '_') s
where s.ItemNumber = 4
```

Another option might be to simple leverage PARSENAME.

```
select PARSENAME(replace(@str, '_', '.'), 1)
```

This may or may not work with your real data. If you have more than 4 elements it will not do what you want. If you have periods in your actual data it will not work as expected either.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Splitfunction]
(
    @queryArg NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @delimiterArg NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @posArg int
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @queryString nvarchar(MAX) = ISNULL(@queryArg,'');
    DECLARE @queryLen int = LEN(@queryString);
    DECLARE @delimiterString nvarchar(MAX) = ISNULL(@delimiterArg,'');
    DECLARE @delimiterLen int = LEN(@delimiterString);
    DECLARE @startPos int = 1;
    DECLARE @endPos int = CHARINDEX(@delimiterString,@queryString);
    DECLARE @queryIndex int = 0;
    -- loop through the string
    WHILE (@startPos<(@queryLen+1)) BEGIN
        -- if the delimiter wasn't found, get all remaining characters
        IF (@endPos=0) SET @endPos=@queryLen+1;
        -- if we're at the index requested return the found string
        IF (@queryIndex=@posArg) RETURN SUBSTRING(@queryString,@startPos,@endPos-@startPos);
        -- advance the start to after the delimiter
        SET @startPos=@endPos+@delimiterLen;
        -- find the next delimiter
        SET @endPos=CHARINDEX(@delimiterString,@queryString,@startPos);
        -- increment the index
        SET @queryIndex += 1;
    END
    RETURN NULL;
END
```

Comment: This does the same as the answer by Sean but splits the string only up to the element you are interested in.  Also the answer isn't behind a registration wall, for casual viewers.

Comment: The answer by Sean is way faster than using a `WHILE` loop.

Comment: @wewesthemenace I'm curious to see profiling which proves it's faster.  What I propose is the basic "nibble splitter" from Jeff Modem's post, modified to avoid the overheads of: modifying the original string, populating a result table, or parsing past the index requested. Instead my suggestion finds the indexed delimiter, and returns a single substring - it does this using operations that are all present in Jeff's (lovely) Tally OH algorithm, but without the overheads of table population, pivot, and parsing of unnecessary delimiters.

Comment: @wewesthemenace I stand corrected - I profiled the two routines running a million times, selecting the 2nd out of 4 delimited items  (the "2214" from the example search string in Sean's answer) and Tally OH was twice as fast.  There must be overhead in the SQL parsing of while loops which the optimized table manipulations outweigh, on top of the string parsing overhead which Jeff identifies in his article.  Good to know.

Comment: wow! Thanks for sharing the results of your test. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of breaking the string you can use this function

**Function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION Split_function_delimiter(@str      VARCHAR(5000),
                                         @POSITION INT)
returns VARCHAR(5000)
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @TEMP   VARCHAR(2),
              @CNTR   INT =1,
              @RESULT VARCHAR(5000),
              @INTR   INT =0,
              @LEN    INT

      SET @LEN =Len(@str)
      WHILE @CNTR <= @LEN
        BEGIN
            SET @TEMP = Substring(@STR, @CNTR, 1)
            IF @TEMP = '_'
              BEGIN
                  SET @INTR += 1
                  IF @INTR = @POSITION
                    BEGIN
                        SET @RESULT = Substring(@STR, @CNTR + 1, CASE
                                                                   WHEN Charindex('_', @STR, @CNTR + 1) - @CNTR < 1 THEN Len(@str)
                                                                   ELSE Charindex('_', @STR, @CNTR + 1) - @CNTR
                                                                 END - 1)

                        BREAK
                    END
              END
            SET @CNTR+=1
        END
      RETURN @RESULT
  END
```

**TESTING**

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(5000) = 'kool_2214_live_dbp123'

SELECT dbo.Split_function_delimiter(@str, 1)--2214
SELECT dbo.Split_function_delimiter(@str, 2)--live
SELECT dbo.Split_function_delimiter(@str, 3)--dbp123
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

Example:

**String** = "pos1-pos2-pos3"

```
REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(String), '-', '.'), 1))
```

With 1 Returns "pos1"

With 2 will return "pos2"...